# Adding Column to populated DataSet

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a column to a dataset that has my sql table data.  I basically wanted to add a column after the data is loaded to keep track of which values are already in the database and which values are new in the datagrid.  Then I can just know which rows to add into the database. I would appreciate any help.

Here is my code, I'm just trying to get the column to show up at this point, I will worry about updating the rows with this new column later.

```
        sqlcom.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text +"', '"+ textBox2.Text +"')";
        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataAdapter sqladapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM members", thisConnect);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqladapt.Fill(ds, "members");

        //add column to dataset?
        ds.Tables["members"].Columns.Add("inDb");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "members";

        thisConnect.Close();
```

Comment: You have the comment as a question. What happens if you try this? What do you think?

Comment: How much _only-an-example_ is this example code? If this is the way you plan on performing an `INSERT`, then read up on [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx).

Comment: my issue is that when I add the column to the table, it doesn't show up in my datagridview.

Comment: I assume that `dataGridView1.`[`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) is set to true? Have you tried an [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.add.aspx) method with a Type? Such as `.Add("inDB", typeof(bool))`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

`ds.Tables["members"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("inDb", typeof(Boolean)));`

another option is to return this field in your select statement,

`select *, cast(1 as bit) as InDb from member`,

which sets true for all values that are returned from table.

You should also consider SQL Parameters to avoid any SQL Injections, for example lets say i enter `-','-');truncate table members;` in first textbox this will delete all rows from members table with no option to retrieve data back

```
sqlcom.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname) 
                       VALUES (@first,@last)";
sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first",textBox1.Text);
sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last",textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the information and now its doing what I wanted.